# How to pass basic authentication base 64 key in headers

Tags: python, python-requests

i was generally trying on apis of paytm.com to code in python through requests module i m passing every postdata and header correctly and it has one header Authentication: Basic "base64encoded string" 
at first i passed it directly in header it didn't worked then passed it through `r=requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=pdata,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('market-app:','9a071762-a499-4bd9-914a-xxxxxxxx'))` and after runnning it and getting `r.request.headers['Headers']` it even gave it the way auth shd had been passed in it but still it didn't gave the response it shd had given the error was `This request requires HTTP authentication.` Where am i missing i am not getting it even i tried `HTTPBasicAuth`.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). At the very least, you need to show what you tried as code.

Comment: Please add link to API documentation for authehtication